# Does MSBuild need Visual Studio to be installed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, msbuild, build-automation

I'm setting up a build server using Atlassian Bamboo. MSBuild is included with the .NET framework, so I believe I can build .NET applications fine at least without VS2010.

We mostly develop in C++ - will I need to install Visual Studio on the build server to build .vcxproj C++ projects, or can this be done only with MSBuild?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you just need the toolset (libraries) see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293607%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much. That link seems to suggest I need Visual Studio 2010? Or perhaps there's a separate download for the libraries? I have VS2010 licenses available for the build server if it's really necessary.

Comment: You should be able to get the toolset from the platform sdk or driver ddk, the point being that you don't need the fullblown IDE installed just msbuild, linker.exe, cl.exe, vcbuildhelper.exe and some other stuff I can't remember, this may be something you can custmomise in the installer

Comment: Plus, Visual Studio 2010 Express contains quite a bit of what you would need, is free, and can be used to produce commercial software without licenses or fees.